# converting post API code to get API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am consuming below API using post. I have another API which I have to consume using get. instead of request.post I used request.get it is giving 401 error. I have to consume another API using GET with basic authentication. anybody can suggest changes for it.

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login/'
var user = 'test35';
var pass = 'mypassword';
request.post(
  {
    uri: url,
    form: { username: user, password: pass }
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('post failed:', err);
    }
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  }
);
```

Comment: Typically you would include an [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) request header with the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Does the response of that post request an authentication token (for example an jwt)?
APIs usually return some key that you can use in further requests, for example, in your headers in an get request